# Conjugate points on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Given a unit speed geodesic $c:[0,l]\to M$, if there is no point that is conjugate to $c(0)$ along $c$, is it true that $\forall r,s\in [0,l]$ $c(s)$ is not conjugate to $c(r)$.

And can a point conjugate to itself?

Comment: Can you clarify your first question? "is it true that all points there is no pair of points $(c(r),c(s))$ conjugate to each other along the curve" doesn't make grammatical sense.

Comment: As to your second question, the answer is no, essentially by definition.

Comment: edited. In my lecture notes, it is written $l>0$ but not necessarily $c(0)\neq c(l)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ignore my second comment -- yes, a point can be conjugate to itself along a nontrivial closed geodesic.